# Per backend configurable forwarding timeout in Traefik proxy?

Tags: traefik

I have a question on ForwardingTimeout configuration in Traefik (https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/#forwarding-timeouts)
Do any backend providers support configuring it per backend instead of globally in traefik proxy? 
Most of the other proxies (haproxy) allow configuring dial-timeout, read-timeout's per backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment.
There's an discussion for this feature and it's still open: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3027